# My sub-square-matrix sum program is finding the sum of the largest rectangle instead

Tags: c++, matrix

I need to write a program that reads a square matrix of integers and outputs the largest sub-**SQUARE**-matrix sum.
The first line of input is an integer which indicates the dimension of the square matrix(n*n), followed by the actual matrix row-by-row.

I have a program working. However, it outputs the largest sum of a rectangle and not a **square which is required.**

Example input:

3

1 2 3

4 5 6

-7 -8 -9

Output:
Should be 16 (2+3+5+6) however it is outputting 21 (1+2+3+4+5+6)

As you can see, it is taking the sum of the rectangle but **I need it to find a square**.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    int mat[100][100];
    cin >> n;

    int sum = 0;
    int maxSum = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++) {
            cin>>mat[i][j];
        }
    }

    for (int k = 0; k<n; k++) {
        for (int l = 0; l<n; l++) {
            sum = sum + mat[k][l];
    
            if (sum < 0) {
                sum = 0;
            }
            if (sum > maxSum) {
                maxSum = sum;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << maxSum;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Stepping through your code with a debugger to see exactly what it is doing should be quite instructive and will likely suggest improvements you can make.

Comment: Get your input done up front and use a std::vector<std::vector<int>>. Then you can iterate the data and find the result. Trying to input data and solve at the same time is a rabbit hole for this type of problem.

Comment: @lakeweb I did what you said and got the input up front and the answer stayed the same, could you please show me how to iterate the data?

Answer (score 0):

You were close with your loops. But you have to sum the square for each iteration if that is what you are looking for. Here I'll assume an input and go from there.

**Edit:** So the summing is clearer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    //initalize(using std::cin here) You can size then load the vectors
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> mat = { {1,2,3},{4,5,6},{-7,-8,-9,} };

    // then do the work...
    int max = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
    //assuming 'square' is 2x2, adjust 'size()-1` if not
    for (size_t i = 0; i < mat.size() - 1; ++i)
        for( size_t j = 0; j < mat.at(0).size() - 1; ++j)
        {
            int sum =
                 mat[i][j] +
                 mat[i][j+1] +
                 mat[i+1][j] +
                 mat[i+1][j+1];

            if (sum > max)
                max = sum;
        }
    std::cout << max << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: This checks 2×2 squares, only. How do you know the sum of 1×1 squares, *k* × *k* squares | 0 ≤ *k* ≤ n(0 <? < n?), to be no greater?